# Alternative to annotations?

Tags: java, annotations

I have situation where I cannot add annotations to class, but is there any way to add some kind of meta data to bean (code) that you cannot edit, but what would survive refactoring? What if I extend bean and then add annotations to that class is that possible?

Comment: Can you clarify how you intend to use the meta-data?

Answer (score 2):

The old way, use marker interfaces, that is interfaces without methods like `Serializable` or `Cloneable`.

Comment: I suspect that if annotations can't be added to a class, that class can't be made to implement a marker interface either.

Comment: @Guillaume Certainly, but he asked ;)

Comment: Having code you have to change but can't modify is the root of much evil.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your IDE, all you need to do is refer to your class or methods or fields in a text files such a properties or XML.  Your IDE will find these and offer to perform a text find/replace when you rename classes/method/fields. (Though some refactors such a moving a method to another class won't work so well)

Answer (score 1):

You could consider AOP
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/aop.html

It allows you to externally add behaviour to specific methods, without editing your class. The extra code can be before, after, or around methods.

Without telling us exactly what you want to achieve, it's hard to guess what you need.

Comment: good idea, but how could you use the information provided by AOP as meta-data for other code? (and sorry I deleted my comment in the other answer, I didn't see your reply)

Comment: I'm not sure, as I said the question is vague. It just strikes me as a possible solution to add behaviour to a class without changing it, which is basically what annotations (can) provide. Meta-data can mean a lot of different things.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need meta data for use from some other code or it should be readable for human?

You can use code instrumentation to add any data into your classes (javassist, some aop etc)

Answer (score 0):

You could add a parallel class hierarchy with meta data. Sort of like the `BeanInfo` classes provide meta data for Java beans.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't modify the code, you could put the meta data in a global map, with the Class as the key.